# ARM Template 'type' property required

Tags: azure-cli

I am trying to deploy a documentDb from the Azure-Cli (version 0.10.2) and so I exported the template directly from azure portal.

This resulted in an error of:

> InvalidRequestContent : The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'defaultValue' on object of type 'DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.arm_document_db.defaultValue'

Changing those to "value" results in:

> InvalidDeploymentParameterType : The type of deployment parameter 'arm_document_db' should not be specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.

checking this page indicates that type is required, but is all in lowercase. This gave the same error.

removing "type" then gives me this error:

> InvalidRequestContent : The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.template.parameters.arm_document_db'

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "arm_document_db": {
        "defaultValue": null,
        "type": "SecureString"
    },
    "arm_document_db01": {
        "defaultValue": "arm-document-db01",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "kind": "DocumentDB",
        "name": "[parameters('arm_document_db01')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
        "location": "Japan West",
        "tags": {},
        "properties": {
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "name": "[parameters('arm_document_db')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
]
}
```

The aka.ms link shows that 'type' is required, however the error says that it isn't. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error is not for azuredeploy.json. It's for azuredeploy.parameters.json.
Remove the "type" field from your parameters file.